# Create a tabbed WPF menu, "ESET Antivirus" - Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

I'm looking for a way to create an application layout for a little tool that looks like the ESET Antivirus UI:

[image: ESET Antivirus UI]

I thought, that I take a TabControl and do a complete Restyling on this whole thing. I created a basic tab layout:

```
<Grid Background="White" Grid.Row="1" >
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem Header="Dashboard">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Projects">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Settings">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>                
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Help &amp; Info">
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

However, I don't have the slightest clue how to get the tabs the way I'd like them to be. I tried a lot with Blend to get the Tabs look the image above, but I don't get it. The triangle would be a nice to have, but the highlighting should be adapted.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are having trouble with trying to make WPF UI elements look exactly the way you want, you should go find the default `<style>` XAML from microsoft and try modifying that directly in your project until you get the desired result.

In case that wasn't clear, you you need to do is follow the links below, copy the style from the pages and put them into the Resources section of your window (or App.xaml, its really up to you).  Then fiddle with them until you get it to look the way you want.

The two styles you'll need to play with are [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [TabItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'd think to a MVVM approach, instead.

Before all, shape the model of the data, as well as the business layer (commands, functions, etc.).
Then, you can "wear" your model (by leveraging a ViewModel) with a ListBox, for the left selector, and a simple ContentControl for the main part.
The selected item of the ListBox should be fed into the content of the body, and a DataTemplateSelector (for instance) will choose the proper visual fragment.

It's just a suggestion. Personally, I've found a bit tricky the TabControl and I seldom use it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

An old trick is to have 2 different sets of images - one for clicked and one for passive (maybe one for mouseover) but clicked image will have the triangle in it. 
This uses static images for buttons, which is very easy to use, but hard to modify on the fly.